# Brackets won't let me change the background colour of even a blank document using external CSS

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I have been using Brackets for a school image and was trying to move div tags next to each other but was experiencing no change in visuals of the code and I wanted to check if there is an issue with the external CSS so I tried to change the background colour to no successes and haven't even been able to change the background colour of a properly set up blank document.

I have been using the following to try to change the colour.

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

And this is the blank html for the purpose of testing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Solitare</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="tex/css">

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something blindingly obvious or is there another issue?

Thank you very much. G. Ward

Comment: post relevant code here

Comment: Did you add the reference to the external css file in the main html page? Please post both html and css code.

Comment: I have added the html code now, apologies for not initially attaching it.

Comment: probably you have a mistake at <link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="tex/css"> try this <link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="text/css">

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much. (feel like a bit of an idiot missing the obvious)

Comment: if it fixed the problem. please approve the answer on the question. thanks

Answer (score 3):

probably you have a mistake at `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="tex/css">` try this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="text/css">`

```css
body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Solitare</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine!
you are only missing 1 thing a 'text' instead of 'tex'

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="tex/css"`

should be

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" type="text/css"`